# get BBM Pin using webworks sdk on Android,windows,IOS

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I am developing an application for Android,IOS,Windows using Phonegap based on bbm.

But I could not find any way to retrieve bbm pin from device.

Is it possible to retrieve bbm pin from device using webworks api?

Comment: To whoever downvoted: this is a valid question. @DK- if you can connect c++ with it you have info in bb/device/HardwareInfo [(example)](https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/blob/master/BB10/deviceInfo/NDK_project/src/template_ndk.cpp)

Comment: @BojanKogoj +1, that's a correct question, there's no reason to downvote it.

Comment: Also check for additional update in my answer related to BBM UUID and AppWorld.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible , Right now BBM does not provide such API may be in future release they provide that

Answer (score 2):

Since WebWorks 2.0 it is possible.

To use this API in your project, add the identity plugin:

```
webworks plugin add com.blackberry.identity
```

and check read-only String `blackberry.identity.uuid`

more information:

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/v2_2/blackberry.identity.html

---

if you mean `uuid` related to the BBM Platform (not the Blackberry device uuid) then if you consider the [following code](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/v2_2/blackberry.bbm.platform.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Create callback invoked when access changes
    document.addEventListener("onaccesschanged", accessChangedCallback);

    function accessChangedCallback(accessible, status) {
        if (status == "unregistered") {
            // App is unregistered, proceed to register
            registerApp();
        } else if (status == "allowed") {
            // Access allowed
        }
        // Listen for other status...
    };

    function registerApp() {
    // Register with the platform
         blackberry.bbm.platform.register({
             uuid: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" // Randomly generated UUID
         });
    }

</script>
```

you can see, that `uuid` used for register app is just randomly generated `uuid`. And for your application when you call registerApp generate your own UUID to be used with BBM platform as a unique identifier.

---

Just found [the following information](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/11/blackberry-webworks-bbm-integration/):

Each application must define its own Universally Unique Identifier (UUID) so that it can uniquely identify itself. This UUID is used to register with the BBM SP servers during testing and development. Applications in the BlackBerry App World™ storefront are assigned their own UUID automatically. In BlackBerry WebWorks, the UUID is stored in the options parameter used in registration.

```
options = {
    uuid: "33490f91-ad95-4ba9-82c4-33f6ad69fbbc"
};

blackberry.bbm.platform.register(options);
```

And below the post there is a short discussion:

```
Q: can you please indicate where/how to find the AppWorld listed application UUID

A: That isn't visible to you.  It's handled automatically.

Q: So how can we use the app's AppWorld UUID to register with BBM?  Which was the context in which you mentioned the UUID.

A: In your code you always use your UUID you created.  When the application is downloaded from App World the OS will automatically swap out your custom UUID with the one from App World.
```

Comment: thanks for reply. My question is very simple. How I can access bbm pin in my android device.

Comment: I read this from the link you provide:   Now I’m here to talk about how you can integrate your BlackBerry® WebWorks™ application with the BBM SP. Most of what will be covered is available to both BlackBerry® OS 5-7 and BlackBerry® 10 applications. However, at the time of writing some of the BBM SP APIs discussed here are available only for BlackBerry OS 5-7 applications — I’ve noted where this is the case. We are planning on adding these to the BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK as well.

Comment: @DK- I am sorry, but I don't have an answer to your questions. Try to ask your questions here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/bd-p/browser_dev